# How to translate this enhanced loop to for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

```
 for (int[] w : weights)
  distance[w[0] - 1][w[1] - 1] = w[2];
```

How to translate this enhanced loop to for loop? where weights and distance are 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is define some iterator (`i` in our case) and iterate over the multidimensional array as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    int[] w = weights[i];

    distance[w[0] - 1][w[1] - 1] = w[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you mean :

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
    distance[weights[i][0] - 1][weights[i][1] - 1] = weights[i][2];
```

**Note** that `w` is replaced by `weights[i]`

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to create an index that iterates to length of weights and use that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
    distance[weights[i][0] - 1][weights[i][1] - 1] = weights[i][2];
```

however this can be hard to read so I'd use a few well named variables instead. I also add some final keywords for readability.

```
for (final int index = 0; index < weights.length; index++)
{
    final int weight0 = weights[index][0] - 1;
    final int weight1 = weights[index][1] - 1;
    final int weight2 = weights[index][2];
    distance[weight0][weight1] = weight2;
}
```

Which style you use and what is more readable is up to you of course.

Note: The use of final above is descriptive and good practice but entirely optional. You can leave it out and the loop will work just as well.

Comment: @ThanaSa Happy to help. Up vote any answers that helped you and select the most correct one as your approved answer. It heps us out :)

Comment: Sorry i'm not privileged to do that yet ;p

Comment: @ThanaSa You can't upvote, but even new users can accept an answer. Just hit the little grayed out checkmark to the left of the answer that you feel best answers your question.